# Oracle select statement based on multiple input parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ref-cursor

How I achieve the following in oracle 11g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sel_tblStateMaster (
p_id                IN       NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, 
p_code                IN       varchar DEFAULT NULL,
p_name                IN       varchar DEFAULT NULL),
p_result     OUT      sys_refcursor
as
begin

// Dummy code
OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM TBLSTATEMASTER;
if not p_code IS NULL
OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM p_result where code=p_code;
end if;

if not p_name IS NULL
OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM p_result where name=p_name;
end if;
end
/
```

I know above specified query is not correct, I just need a corrected solution for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple **IF-ELSE** construct:

```
IF p_code IS NOT NULL AND p_name IS NOT NULL 
THEN
  OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM TBLSTATEMASTER WHERE code=p_code AND NAME=p_name;
ELSE
  OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM TBLSTATEMASTER;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The IF statement should have a then clause

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sel_tblStateMaster (
    p_id                IN       NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, 
    p_code                IN       varchar DEFAULT NULL,
    p_name                IN       varchar DEFAULT NULL),
    p_result     OUT      sys_refcursor
    as
    begin

    // Dummy code
    OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM TBLSTATEMASTER;
    if not p_code IS NULL
    then
    OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM p_result where code=p_code;
    end if;

    if not p_name IS NULL
    then
    OPEN p_result FOR SELECT * FROM p_result where name=p_name;
    end if;
    end;
```